# I need a generalized approach for checking input parameters of methods

Tags: c#, validation, wcf

I have Web Service (.svc) which has many methods. Some of them get object(s), some of them get basic types (both nullable and not; either reference or value types, mutable or immutable, anything is possible)

I would like to implement a mechanism that checks each and every parameter fed to the methods against some rules. For example, Date Range for DateTime, character limitation for string types, range limits for integer types etc.

I know how to use Reflection, so I can get parameters, determine types and check values. The missing information is to write a mechanism which redirects each and every method call before running the code inside for parameter validation.

It is possible to write a validation class and call it at the start of each method but I would like to implement a more generalized approach which can be the next standard to implement Web services.

I thought that this could be done with a ServiceMethodDispatcher class which is called via the svc.cs file first with method name and parameters. There runs a Business Logic to check parameters than redirect to actual Business class method which really does the work.

Comment: You're overthinking it. 
use parameter validations inside each method.  The validation code itself might be generalized, but calling it - well, that's the job for the method that's going to use the parameters.

Comment: There are about 500+ methods in multiple endpoints. Unfortunately doing that would bring so much workload and will take so much time :(

Comment: You can try to use a message interceptor to achieve this, use IDispatchMessageInspector on the client to intercept messages on the server, and use IClientMessageInspector on the server to intercept messages on the client. For more information about Message interceptor:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8